# Dynamics CRM 2011 - Getting too many rows back from a retrievemultiple on salesordersdetail

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a plugin that is registered Update, Order, Post Operation. In the plugin I perform a retrievemultiple on the salesorderdetail. The problem I'm having is that there are 3 products that make up the order but I am returning 5 rows from the retrieve operation. I have added and deleted the same product multiple times during my testing and I'm not sure if that's what's causing the problem. I was thinking that after deleting a product from the order it may set a flag and get deleted after, but I don't see a status code or state code as an attribute. Why would it return too many rows?

Here is my code...

```
// Set the properties of the QueryExpression object.
orderDetailQuery.EntityName = "salesorderdetail";
orderDetailQuery.ColumnSet = orderDetailColumnSet;

EntityCollection salesOrderDetail = service.RetrieveMultiple(orderDetailQuery);

orderProductQuery.EntityName = "product";
orderProductQuery.ColumnSet = orderProductColumnSet;

foreach (var orderDetail in salesOrderDetail.Entities)
{
     if(orderDetail.Attributes.Contains("productid"))
     {
         productGuid = ((EntityReference)orderDetail["productid"]).Id;
         Entity product = service.Retrieve("product", productGuid, orderProductColumnSet);
      }
 }
```

Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted does not show you filtering for the specific `Order`.

I would expect that to retrieve all entities of that type in the system.

To filter, assuming you are using a `QueryByAttribute`, is to add an filter along the lines of:

```
var query = new QueryByAttribute();
query.EntityName = "salesorderdetail";
query.AddAttributeValue("orderid", orderId);//orderId is the Id of the parent Order 
orderDetailQuery.EntityName = "salesorderdetail";
orderDetailQuery.ColumnSet = orderDetailColumnSet;
var results = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

That way you are restricting your query to just products for the given order.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what I was thinking. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your filtering is implemented. Here's a shot from the hip on how you could query for instances of *SalesOrderDetail* entity, fetching the values of *fieldName1* and *fieldName2* fields provided that the it's linked to the order with guid *orderId*.

```csharp
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
{
  EntityName = "salesorderdetail",
  ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("fieldName1", "fieldName2"),
  Criteria = new FilterExpression
  {
    Conditions = 
    {
      new ConditionExpression 
      {
        AttributeName = "orderid",
        Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
        Values = { orderId }
      }
    }
  }
};
```